# Silex and htaccess to /web

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, silex

I m actually creating a simple application using Silex and I m having some problems.

Actually, I run on an Apache 2 server and I have the fallback /index.php set in my ht access at the root of my application.

In fact, I actually have to get these kind of routes :

> http://127.0.0.1/appname/web/index.php/route

And I need something like

> http://127.0.0.1/route

I absolutely don't know how to proceed...

Can you help me a bit ?

Comment: This kind of basic usage is always in the doc .
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Just make sure to use the *RewriteBase /appname/web*

Comment: Also, if you hold your app code inside *appname* you're making your code public, this is a really bad practice, your webroot should be the *web* folder (the one and only meant to be publicly accessible).

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `.htaccess` to change your root directory and to replace the index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appname/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2index.php [QSA]
```